# How can I typeset the following nested matrices?

Tags: matrices

[image: Sketch]

Note that it has to be square brackets. The big A can be normal size if necessary as long as it's still centered on the left. I could also live with it being below the outer matrix annotating the left hand side with curly braces.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[
\begin{array}{ @{} c c : c c @{} }
\hphantom{\ddots}
&
  \left[
  \begin{array}{ @{} ccc @{}}
  \phantom{1} \\ & \phantom{1} \\ && \phantom{1}
  \end{array}
  \right.
&
  \left.
  \begin{array}{ @{} ccc @{}}
  1 \\ & 1 \\ && 1
  \end{array}
  \right]
\\
\multicolumn{2}{c:}{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\scalebox{5}{A}}}} && \ddots
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After replacing `\multicolumn{2}{c:}{...}` by

```
\multicolumn{2}{c:}{\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{.2\height}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{5}{A}}}}
```

the output will be

[image]

The amount of raising has been guessed. It *may* be computed, but I don't think you need such an object more than once.

Comment: This is really good. I didn't think of using \left[, \right[, and arrays at all. Though, can you also think of a way to center the A vertically?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff Added.